# how to add user input to a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to build a graph from an api of weather website. I want user to input 3 cities that I would like to know the current temp in and then make a dictionary from the api and the user input `{name of the city - user input: the currently temp from the api}` and then make the dictionry to a graph `{name of the city: the currently temp from the api}`

the api I use is `drksky api`
I mostly use this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt for the graph
```

```
import forecastio
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



def read_key_from_file():
    hFile = open(file_name,'r')
    for line in hFile:
        Mykey = line
    hFile.close()
    Mykey = line
    return  Mykey

def get_geo_location(location):
    location = Nominatim().geocode(location)
    lat = location.latitude
    lon = location.longitude
    return location, lat, lon


def comperison_graph(Mykey): 

    if daily_temp_dict == {}:
        a = input("Enter first city name in lower case letter: ")
        daily_temp_dict[a] = ""
        b = input("Enter second city name in lower case letter: ")
        daily_temp_dict[b] = ""
        c = input("Enter third city name in lower case letter: ")
        daily_temp_dict[c] = ""
        for city in daily_temp_dict.keys():
                location, lat, lon = get_geo_location(city)
                forecast = forecastio.load_forecast(Mykey, lat, lon)
                daily_temp_dict[city] = forecast.currently().temperature
                data =  daily_temp_dict
                names = list(data.keys())
                print(names)
                values = list(data.values())
                print(values)
                plt.bar(0,values[0],tick_label=names[0])
                plt.bar(1,values[1],tick_label=names[1])
                plt.bar(2,values[2],tick_label=names[2])
                plt.xticks(range(0,3),names)
                plt.savefig('fruit.png')
                plt.show()
```

the problem is that im getting in a result a graph like this :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RpJ7c.jpg

and i need only the last one with the 3 cities

Unfortunately I can't make it

can someone please help me?

Comment: *unfortunately i can't make it* - why? is there an error? is the output not as tyou expect it to be?

Comment: Hi, please do some edit of your question in order to increase readability, you will get more attention and more chance to have an answer.

Comment: it should be a graph from a dictionry (x plot: name of the city , y plot: current temperature from the api)

Comment: And what is this line ? `end if `

Comment: i fixed the code pls some one can help me ?

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new key with an empty string `""` as value:

```
if cities_for_txt_file == {}:
    a = input("Enter first city name in lower case letter: ")
    cities_for_txt_file[a] = ""
    b = input("Enter second city name in lower case letter: ")
    cities_for_txt_file[b] = ""
    c = input("Enter third city name in lower case letter: ")
    cities_for_txt_file[c] = ""
    for city in cities_for_txt_file:
            location, lat, lon = get_geo_location(city)
            forecast = forecastio.load_forecast(Mykey, lat, lon)
```

And then assign `forecast` as value to the city:

```
            cities_for_txt_file[city] = forecast
```

Note: As you did not provide the full code, it is very possible that it does not handle errors, such as a city not found with your `get_geo_location()`. I recommend you to add some "try / catch" to your code.

EDIT: As you edited your question, this is my answer to your new question.

You should not do all the plotting part in the loop but after it. It should look like this:

```
    for city in daily_temp_dict.keys():
        location, lat, lon = get_geo_location(city)
        forecast = forecastio.load_forecast(Mykey, lat, lon)
        daily_temp_dict[city] = forecast.currently().temperature
    data =  daily_temp_dict
    names = list(data.keys())
    print(names)
    values = list(data.values())
    print(values)
    plt.bar(0,values[0],tick_label=names[0])
    plt.bar(1,values[1],tick_label=names[1])
    plt.bar(2,values[2],tick_label=names[2])
    plt.xticks(range(0,3),names)
    plt.savefig('fruit.png')
    plt.show()
```

Comment: its from the api , can you help me from here how i will make it into a graph  matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Comment: `from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
get_geo_location(location):
    location = Nominatim().geocode(location)
    lat = location.latitude
    lon = location.longitude
    return location, lat, lon`           from

Comment: @kinglebron I edited my answer for your new question.

Comment: @kinglebron please mark it as answer if it solved your problem

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries don't work like that, dictionaries don't support append()

I think you have no idea how dictionaries work, I would suggest you to read little bit

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/python_dictionary

https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/dictionary

Comment: i learnd a bit about the subject and edited my question, can you pls help me now ?